# ubuntu launching help on multiboot usb (created with yumi)

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I installed ubuntu and another os on a 64gb flash drive and allocated 20gb for saving files and settings on ubuntu(live persistence), but im confused as to how it works. When i boot ubuntu it asks to "try" or "install alongside current os". If every time i select to just "try" wont that reset itself every time? i want to be able to have everything i do in ubuntu saved on my flash drive. any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have persistent storage set up then "try Ubuntu without installing" won't reset your installation. That is the option you want to select.

Comment: yumi lets you choose how much storage you want for ubuntu but is there a step beyond that, that i need to do because i tested the "try" mode and nothing saved.

Comment: Try using unetbootin. Download [here](http://unetbootin.github.io/)

Comment: thanks ill try it. i didnt think unetbootin let you create a multiboot though?

Comment: it does allow persistent storage. Multiboot only if you create 2 partitions yourself, then install one on each partition.